# how to convert .vstheme file into .Xaml theme

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I have Default.vstheme which is default them used by Visual Studio 2010; I want to use this in my application. How can I convert this into XAML file so that I can use in my application.

Thanks
Ocean

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible in a straight-forward way. You have to extract the themes from VS assembly files and then fill them with the colors.

More details in answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4842736/where-can-i-get-themes-for-wpf-controls-that-resemble-the-visual-studio-2010-inte) question.